# How to Integrate Restful Spring Mvc 4 annotation based configuration with Soap?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, soap, spring-ws

I have configured Spring Mvc 4 with Restful services(annotation based) in my E commerce Web Application.  Now I need to also use SOAP in order to integrate with a bank API . **My Spring  MVC 4 configuration is completely annotation based and is using JSon** .

1. How do I configure Soap to run in Spring Mvc 4 Application?
2. Which method is good in Soap for development Contract First or Contract       last?
3. Is there any way  I can avoid using XML and use only Java classes
       in soap for Request and response and keep all Soap configuration only in          Java?
4. If the above method possible will that method be appropriate for development?
5. How do I add Soap Configuration to My Existing Spring Mvc 4 Restful
   Web Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the following link https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/ for consuming a web service and integrated it with my spring mvc 4 application and it works.